# How to organize models of a project?

Tags: scene

Is it possible to copy a model from one file to another and all changes made to the object in either of the two files are inserted and saved in all files that have this object with the intention of organizing the production?

Comment: I've only heard about linked object but only the original object can be changed

Comment: Hello and welcome. English is mandatory language for the site. If you are not comfortable writing in English feel free to use any online translation service.

Comment: The general industry term for this is "external referencing" or, simply, "references".

I am new to Blender, but look forward to seeing what options there might be for doing it.